# How to use UiField in another class in GWT

Tags: java, oop, gwt, user-interface, widget

Currently I have a label and image. When the label or the image is pressed it will bring up Panel one. Once panel one is up there is three button options. If it press done a check mark will appear. If it press cancel then an X will appear and when it press pending a clock will appear.

**This is the tab click where the image and label is located**

```
public class buttonclickers extends Composite {

boolean buttonone = false;
boolean buttontwo = false;

private static buttonclickersUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
        .create(buttonclickersUiBinder.class);
@UiField PushButton button_1;
@UiField PushButton button_2;
@UiField Image checkimage;
@UiField Label label_one;

interface buttonclickersUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, buttonclickers> {
}

public buttonclickers() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
}

@UiHandler("button_1")

void onButton_1Click(ClickEvent event) {
    buttonone = true;
    buttontwo = false;
    AppUtils.EVENT_BUS.fireEvent(new ButtonEvent());


}
@UiHandler("button_2")
void onButton_2Click(ClickEvent event) {
    buttontwo = true;
    buttonone = false;
    AppUtils.EVENT_BUS.fireEvent(new ButtonEvent());


}
@UiHandler("checkimage")
void onCheckimageClick(ClickEvent event) {
    //Window.alert("hit");
    AppUtils.EVENT_BUS.fireEvent(new ButtonEvent());
    checkimage.setUrl("mvpwebapp/gwt/clean/images/xmark.png");

}

@UiHandler("label_one")
void onLabel_oneClick(ClickEvent event) {
    AppUtils.EVENT_BUS.fireEvent(new ButtonEvent());
    checkimage.setUrl("mvpwebapp/gwt/clean/images/xmark.png");


}
public int checkbuttonclick()
{
    int butt_one = 1;
    int butt_two = 2;

    if(buttonone == true)
    {
        return butt_one;
    }
    else if(buttontwo == true)
    {
        return butt_two;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}



}
```

**Here is the class where I want to be able to use**

```
public class panelOne extends Composite {
boolean button_cancel = false;
boolean button_pending = false;
boolean button_done = false;
private static panelOneUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
        .create(panelOneUiBinder.class);
@UiField PushButton done;
@UiField PushButton cancel;
@UiField PushButton pending;

interface panelOneUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, panelOne> {
}

public panelOne() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
}

@UiHandler("cancel")
void onCancelClick(ClickEvent event) {
    button_cancel = true;
    button_pending = false;
    button_done = false;
    Window.alert("cancel");
    AppUtils.EVENT_BUS.fireEvent(new ButtonEvent());

}
@UiHandler("pending")
void onPendingClick(ClickEvent event) {
    button_cancel = false;
    button_pending = true;
    button_done = false;
    Window.alert("pending");
    AppUtils.EVENT_BUS.fireEvent(new ButtonEvent());

}
@UiHandler("done")
void onDoneClick(ClickEvent event) {
    button_cancel = false;
    button_pending = false;
    button_done = true;
    Window.alert("done");
    AppUtils.EVENT_BUS.fireEvent(new ButtonEvent());


}
}
```

I want to put

> checkimage.setUrl("mvpwebapp/gwt/clean/images/xmark.png");

into my panelOne class instead of having it in the buttonclickers class. I am doing that because I want to change the image from a check to an X. I looked up some stuff online, but I am pretty confused as to how to apply this.

Thank You

Comment: Are these two classes in the same package?

Comment: yes sir! I found a work around where i just call functions in the class that has the UIfields.